# VSC Python : issue with anaconda when debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Background: I had previously installed Python in VSC. I installed anaconda for the purpose of learning how to use the platform.

When I tried to configure VSC to use Anaconda's Python I was unable to debug automatically.

I attach an image about it.

[Code without debugging and VSC colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLolZ.png)

[Python Interpreter on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNxyT.png)

Note: The code marks errors AFTER running it, not instantly, as I was used to.

Please excuse my ignorance regarding the subject. I installed VSC and changed the interpreter of the project generally to anaconda in case it is deemed relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem caused by using the Python environment in Anaconda, but the current choice of Python language services.

When I used the default "`Jedi`" language service, I reproduced the problem you described:

[image]

**Solution**: Please use "Microsoft" or "Pylance" language service: (in settings.json)

`"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",` or `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",`

Please reload VS Code after setting, then open the ".py" file and wait for the language service to load.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :)